# string concatenation of sine wave

Tags: string, string-concatenation, scilab

Hello I am trying to create a title that includes my sine wave equation with variables.

```
% Set up initial parameters    
pi = 3.14;      % Make a variable called pi, and set it equal to 3.14    
A = 1985;       % Set the amplitude (A) equal to 5    
f = 7/3;        % Set the frequency (f) equal to 10    
p = pi/9;       % Set the phase (p) equal to 0    

% Create a time axis    
dt = 0.1;                    % Set the time step to be relatively small     
t = [0 : dt : 2.*pi];        % Create a list of time points from 0 thrugh 2*pi in steps of dt       

% Calculate the sine wave    
y = A.*sin(f.*t+p);   

y

% Graphical Display    
plot(t,y,'ko-')    
xlabel('Time, sec', 'fontsize', 6)    
ylabel ('Amplitude', 'fontsize', 6)

strA = msprintf('%1.1f', A);    
strf = msprintf('%1.1f', f);    
strp = msprintf('%1.1f', p);    
titlestr = 'y = ' + strA +' .* sin( ' + strf + ' .* t + ' + strp + ')'    
title(titlestr, 'fontsize', 6)
```

Here is what I have done so far.
I don't get the title when plotting this equation.
Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Scilab are you using ? It works for me with 5.4.0.

By the way, you should use %pi instead of declaration pi and Scilab uses // for comments, not %